# Zend project return a fatal error: Class 'Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Registry' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, wamp

My zend project returns the following error :

[image]

i dont know when it happen.I followed this video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_L9JxYf80Kk&hd=1.

Add the following datas in **application.ini** file

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.dbname = "zend_test"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "123456"

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded from Zend framework 2 to 1 and the error disappeared.